# Frequency of specific symbols on each line of a text file

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am making a C program that counts the occurrence of the symbol `;` and `.` and display their frequency for each line of a text file.

My code only works with only one symbol counter for dotcoma (counts `;`) and when I add another counter varriable coma(counts `.`) it gives me an error.

> Stack arround varriable was corrupted.

Here is the full code:

```
   #ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /* Да си изключа предупрежденията*/
    #endif

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <conio.h>/* For exit() function */

    int main()
    {
        char file_name[1000];
        FILE *file2 = 0;

        gets(file_name);
        int rows = 1;//broq na vsichki redove
        int dotcoma[150];//broq na ;
        int coma[150];//broq na .
        int j;
        char c;

        file2 = fopen(file_name, "r");//otvarq faial za chetene
        if (file2 == NULL){
            printf("Cannot open %s\n", file_name);
            exit(2);
        }//if

        for (j = 0; j<150; j++)
            dotcoma[j] = 0;
        coma[j] = 0;
        do{
            c = fgetc(file2);
            if (c == '\n') rows++;
            else{
                if (c == ';')
                dotcoma[rows - 1]++;
                if (c == '.')
                coma[rows-1]++;
            }
        } while (c != EOF);//chete do kraq na faila


        if (ferror(file2)){
            printf("Error reading file.\n");
            exit(2);
        }//if

        printf("The number of the symbols on a row ");
        for (j = 0; j<rows; j++){
            printf("Row %d: %f  %f\n", j + 1, (float)dotcoma[j], (float)coma[j]);

        }
        _getche();
        if (fclose(file2) == EOF){
            printf("Cannot close %s\n", file_name);
            exit(2);

            _getche();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid making a new cycle for coma ? like (k=0;k<150;k++) ..... coma[k]++;...... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix your `coma` initialization! You forgot the brackets!

```
for (j = 0; j<150; j++){
    dotcoma[j] = 0;
    coma[j] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure thing @IliqnLalov! Don't forget to rate and close the question if this doubt was clarified.

Comment: I tried to +1 it, but i do not have the needed rank yet.

Comment: That's true! But, if I'm not mistaken, you can choose "the best answer", thus closing the thread :). Check this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

```
 #ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /* Да си изключа предупрежденията*/
    #endif

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <conio.h>/* For exit() function */

    int main()
    {
        char file_name[1000];
        FILE *file2 = 0;

        gets(file_name);
        int rows = 1;//broq na vsichki redove
        int dotcoma[150];//broq na ;
        int coma[150];//broq na .
        int j;
        char c;

        file2 = fopen(file_name, "r");//otvarq faial za chetene
        if (file2 == NULL){
            printf("Cannot open %s\n", file_name);
            exit(2);
        }//if

        for (j = 0; j<150; j++)
{
            dotcoma[j] = 0;
        coma[j] = 0;
}
        do{
            c = fgetc(file2);
            if (c == '\n') rows++;
            else{
                if (c == ';')
                dotcoma[rows - 1]++;
                if (c == '.')
                coma[rows-1]++;
            }
        } while (c != EOF);//chete do kraq na faila


        if (ferror(file2)){
            printf("Error reading file.\n");
            exit(2);
        }//if

        printf("The number of the symbols on a row ");
        for (j = 0; j<rows; j++){
            printf("Row %d: %f  %f\n", j + 1, (float)dotcoma[j], (float)coma[j]);

        }
        _getche();
        if (fclose(file2) == EOF){
            printf("Cannot close %s\n", file_name);
            exit(2);

            _getche();
            return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

the return statement is inside the if(fclose...) this means the compiler will raise a warning about missing return statement

the initialization of dotcoma and coma arrays is failing becuase the 'if' only handles one code block and the coma[j] =0; is not inside a code block, This is another good reason to ALWAYS place { and } around every code block

under DOS/Windows, a new line is two characters, so this line: if (c == '\n') shows that 'c' should be an int, not a char

regarding this line: FILE *file2 = 0; file2 is a pointer, not an integer, so the line should be: FILE *file2 = NULL;

to avoid edit problems and simplify future maintenance, the 'magic number' 150 should be defined as '#define MAX_COUNT (150)' then MAX_COUNT should be used in all cases rather than the literal 150
Similar considerations should be applied for file_name

the function: getchar() returns a int value (so EOF can be recognized) so this line: 'char c;' should be 'int c;'

the exit() prototype is in stdlib.h not conio.h

regarding this line: gets(file_name); gets() is full of security problems and many other problems. It is depreciated from the C language. Much better to use fgets() as, amongst other things, it limits the number of characters read, so input buffer overflow does not occur.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* For exit() function */
#include <string.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /* Да си изключа предупрежденията*/
    #include <conio.h>
#endif

#define MAX_ROWS (150)
#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN (1000)

int main()
{
    char file_name[MAX_FILENAME_LEN];
    FILE *file2 = NULL;

    if( NULL == fgets(file_name, MAX_ROWS, stdin)
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE )
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    int rows = 1;//broq na vsichki redove
    int dotcoma[MAX_ROWS] = {0};//broq na ;
    int coma[MAX_ROWS] = {0};//broq na .
    int j; // index/loop counter
    int c; // char input from console

    if( NULL == (file2 = fopen(file_name, "r") )//otvarq faial za chetene
    {
        perror( "fopen failed for input file" );
        exit(2);
    }//if

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( EOF != (c = fgetc(file2) )
    {
        switch( c )
        {
            case '\n':
                rows++;
                break;

            case ';':

                dotcoma[rows - 1]++;
                break;

            case '.':
                coma[rows-1]++;
                break;

            default: // all other characters
                break;
        } // end switch
    }  // end while

    printf("The number of the symbols on a row ");
    for (j = 0; j<rows; j++)
    {
        printf("Row %d: %f  %f\n", j + 1, (float)dotcoma[j], (float)coma[j]);
    }

    fclose( file2 );
    getchar(); // wait for user to read screen and enter a char

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```